# Grab value from sql table and assign to a row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foreach

Well, I thought I had solved this problem on my own until I tried it out, working in SQL 2008.

I have two tables, table1 has a single column with a few thousand (available) IDs .  Table2 gets refreshed every day with a new group of users who need one of these IDs from Table1 assigned.

I then need to remove that ID from Table1 so it doesn't get reassigned. The problem I am having is that I don't know how to make this loop through the rows in table2 (usually less than 50) and assign the next lowest ID from table1?  Suggestions are appreciated!  My code below selects the correct value but my update statement just updates all the values to the lowest value in table1, so how does one 'rinse and repeat' for each row?

```
DECLARE @nextid int
SET @nextid = (SELECT uid FROM table1
WHERE uid = (SELECT MIN(uid) FROM table1))

UPDATE table2 
SET uid = @nextid
WHERE uid IS NULL

DELETE FROM usable_ids
WHERE uid = @nextid
```

Table1

```
+------+
| uid  |  
+-------
| 555  |
| 556  |
| 557  |
| 558  | 
| 559  |
| 560  |
+------+
```

Table2

```
+---------+--------+-----------+
| UID     | Status | hire_date | 
+---------+--------+-----------+
|         | happy  | 10/10/2005|
|         | sad    | 12/01/2009|
+---------+--------+-----------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into cursors?

Comment: Please tag the question with the specific DBMS you're using.

Comment: Do you see anything redundant in `SET @nextid = (SELECT uid FROM table1 WHERE uid = (SELECT MIN(uid) FROM table1))`?

Comment: huh, I don't remember why I did that.... yes it looks redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea.  Assign each id to be assigned a sequential number, then use this to assign the ids to the known slots.  Then, delete the appropriate ids from the table:

```
declare @NumToDelete int;
select @NumToDelete = count(*) from table1 where uid is null;

with toupdate as (
      select t2.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from table2
      where uid is null
     )
update tu
    set uid = t1.uid
    from toupdate tu join
         (select t1.uid, row_number() over (order by uid) as seqnum
          from table1
         ) t1
         on t1.seqnum = tu.seqnum;

with todelete as (
      select t1.*, row_number() over (order by uid) as seqnum
      from table1
     )
delete from todelete where seqnum <= @NumToDelete;
```

For the record, I think it would be a better idea to flag the records in table1 for deletion rather than removing them using `delete`.

Comment: OK, this is really cool, I don't know how you wrote that in ~3 minutes.  I had to make one small change, the Select @NumToDelete should reference Table2.  This is really awesome! thanks Gordon!